# PrimeFaces doesn't open dialog when converter attribute is set

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, dialog, converters

I have a page where I open a dialog via p:commandButton. everything works well when no converter-attribute is set for the p:pickList, but when it is the dialog refuses to open.

here is the xhtml (only relevant parts):

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="eventDialog" resizable="false" header="Event">

    <h:form>

        <p:panelGrid id="eventPanel" columns="2"> 

            <h:outputLabel value="Participants" />

            <p:pickList id="participants" value="#{eventBean.dualList}" var="person" 
                itemValue="{person}" showCheckbox="true" 
                converter="#{eventBean.personConverter}" showSourceFilter="true"     
                showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" 
                itemLabel="#{person.name}, #{person.forename}"  />

            <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Personen</f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="targetCaption">Participant</f:facet>  


            <p:commandButton value="Save" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                action="#{eventBean.saveEvent()}" onsuccess="eventDialog.hide()" 
                update="@all" ajax="false" />

        </p:panelGrid>  

    </h:form>

</p:dialog>

<h:form id="eventForm">

    <p:commandButton value="Create Event" action="#{eventBean.createEvent()}"     
        oncomplete="eventDialog.show()" update=":dialog" styleClass="spaceBottom2" />

</h:form>
```

and the bean EventBean (only relevant parts):

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EventBean {

    public EventBean() {    
        converter = new PersonConverter(#list of persons);
    }

    public PersonConverter getPersonConverter() {
        return converter;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why it wouldn't work with the converter, which does what it should in another page.

Comment: 1. Don't try to manage the converter yourself like you're doing now (calling `new` and such). Define a standalone converter and reference appropriately. 2. Look in your javascript console. If there are any conversion errors you're missing on the webpage, it'll be in the console

Comment: I assume by standalone you mean to define it as an @FacesConverter and loading the list each time seems like bad design to me, or is it not?
I don't know what you mean by javascript console, but apart from the pickList the converter works fine.

Comment: You're right, you shouldn't be instantiating a list everytime. The best practice is injecting the list by means of a DAO into the converter. By Javascript console, I mean the developer console in your browser. Most modern browsers provide this under the "developer tools" menu.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with PF, I always called my variables the same as the getters and setters, otherwise I came across a lot of issues.

In your XML you have

```
converter="#{eventBean.personConverter}"
```

I may be wrong, but I believe it will look up getter for the variable `personConverter`.

But in your bean you call the variable just `converter`. Try renaming it to `personConverter`.

Comment: odd, I've never experienced such a problem. I tried renaming the variable, with no success. thanks for the effort though.